# What are the basic mechanism, components or parts to generate relative movements?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, design, kinematics, biomechanics

I'm an engineer in industrial design and despite that I studied mechanics, kinematics and dynamics, I got difficulties when I try to label or find components which could enable my designs have relative movements, i.e. one part rotates inside other.

I know I can design most of them but I guess that some must be already created and would like to know how to search them, instead designing new ones or asking for help in each specific project.

What are the basics relative movements and components that generates them?

**EDIT**

I'm trying to find a ***"movements library"***, to be able to find what are the most common movements and what mechanisms or components are used to achieve them. For example, materials libraries are pretty common in many countries, in them you can find a huge list of materials, with their properties, application and providers.

Comment: Are you looking for physical components that rotate? The general name for such components? Or how to build/make them? It seems like you have multiple different questions in here. Please [edit] your question to add some more information.

Comment: Kevin, my comment is inline with @hazzey. I would recommend rephrasing the question with sketch images to something like if possible to, I have the following design where part A rotates inside part B. But the cost to manufacture is too high, how can I reduce cost or find an alternative low cost solution. This type of question is more direct and is more likely to attract responses.

Comment: Hello @hazzey and *Mahendra Gunawardena* I hope that now is easier to understand. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a fascinating historical collection of mechanisms compiled in the late 19th century here: [Mechanical Movements](http://507movements.com/about.html) and somebody is working through the task of making animations of them for the website.

Manufacturing technology has progressed since then, but the basic ideas are timeless. We used to have a printed copy of this book in our "office library" before the internet existed, as a source of design inspiration.